# How to resolve this error in pycharm using python . I am getting this error whenever I try to install a package . I have given all the permissions

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I have been using pycharm with python . I have installed a lot of packages but never got this error earlier . So can you pls help me out with this . I have given a lot of permissions but still I am getting this error.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\raywin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-_yvcqn13\\pip.exe'
Check the permissions
```

Comment: Hey there, I have been using pycharm with python . I have installed a lot of packages but never got this error earlier . So can you pls help me out with this . I have given a lot of permissions but still I am getting this error.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding additional information as a comment as comments could get removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.